# Workmanager and sensor data fetching on Android

Tags: android, database, sensors, worker

I am developing an app that fetches data from sensors of android and stores them in an SQLite database either when the app is running, or in the background. For the latter option, i designed a workmanager to do the necessary work, but since i am fairly new to the library, i am having some difficulties comprehending how to recieve the data back to the activity in order to be stored to the sqlite database. Here is the relevant code from the app:

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    displayNotification("sensor data recording" , "process is running")

    sensorManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

    initSensors()
    registerListeners()

    return Result.success(sensorData)
}

private fun initSensors() {
    accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    accelometerSensorEventListener = object : SensorEventListener {
        override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {

            for (i in 0 until event!!.values.size) {
                accelerometerValues[i] = event.values[i]
            }

            //keep the time stamp for each event
            if (!acceleratorTimeStampSet) {
                acceleratorTimeStampSet = true
                initialAcceleratorTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
            //set the timestamps
            val timestampX: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() - initialAcceleratorTimeStamp
            accelerometerValuesTimeStampCounter++
            //store the timestamps
            accelerometerValuesTimeStamps.add(timestampX)


            val accelSensorTriplets = ArrayList<Float>(3)
            if (accelSensorTriplets.size == 0) {
                accelSensorTriplets.add(0, event.values[0])
                accelSensorTriplets.add(1, event.values[1])
                accelSensorTriplets.add(2, event.values[2])
            } else {
                accelSensorTriplets.set(0, event.values[0])
                accelSensorTriplets.set(1, event.values[1])
                accelSensorTriplets.set(2, event.values[2])
            }
            //add a dateTime Object value to the array
            val dateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
            if (!allTimeStampsAccel.contains(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))) {
                allTimeStampsAccel.add(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))
                if (!allTimeStamps.contains(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))) {
                    allTimeStamps.add(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))
                }
                var pair1 = Pair<Float, String>(
                    accelSensorTriplets.get(0),
                    allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)
                )
                var pair2 = Pair<Float, String>(
                    accelSensorTriplets.get(1),
                    allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)
                )
                var pair3 = Pair<Float, String>(
                    accelSensorTriplets.get(2),
                    allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)
                )
                var pairArrayList = ArrayList<Pair<Float, String>>(3)
                pairArrayList.add(pair1)
                pairArrayList.add(pair2)
                pairArrayList.add(pair3)
                accelerometerAllValuesForStore.add(pairArrayList)
                Log.d(
                    "DATA",
                    "accel data with timestamp : ${allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)}"
                )
            }
            //add the data for the accelerometer chart
            Log.d("SQL", "ACCEL ${allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)}")

        }

        override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {

        }
    }


var handler = Handler()
var runnableCode : Runnable = object : Runnable
{
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun run() {

        sensorData = Data.Builder()
            .put("accelerometerAllSensorValues" , accelerometerAllValuesForStore)
            .put("accelerometerTimeStamps" , allTimeStampsAccel)
            .put("tempAllSensorValues" , temperatureAllValuesForStore)
            .put("allTempTimeStamps" , allTimeStampsTemp)
            .put("gyroAllValuesForStore" , gyroscopeAllValuesForStore)
            .put("allGyroTimeStamps" , allTimeStampsGyro)
            .put("allLinAccelValuesForStore" , linAccelAllValuesForStore)
            .put("linAccelTimeStamps" , allTimeStampsLinAccel)
            .put("allOrientationValuesForStore" , orientationAllValuesForStore)
            .put("orientationTimeStamps" , allTimeStampsOrientation)
            .put("allRotationValuesForStore" , rotationAllValuesForStore)
            .put("allRotationTimeStamps" , allTimeStampsRotation)
            .build()


        handler.postDelayed(this, 20000)
    }

}
handler.post(runnableCode)
```

....function code continued...

And from the main activity, the observer for the workInfo data returned from the worker is as follows:

```
   var request = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SensorWorkManager::class.java).build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(request)
    WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(request.id)
        .observe(this , Observer<WorkInfo> {
            var status = it.state.name

            if (it != null)
            {
                if (it.state.isFinished)
                {
                    var sensorData = it.outputData
                    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        storeAllDataToSQlDatabase()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

However, i am having the data result returned with the Result.Success() method immediatelly and i am not able to postpone the livedata, in order for the sensor data to be fetched (with a period of 20 sec, as the handler above depicts). As such, i am getting back from the worker an emtpy workInfo.

I am pretty sure i am doing something wrong with the Worker implementation.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it onetime request?

Comment: Yes, it is not a periodic one.

Comment: Periodic request minimum delay 15mins onces.... Foreground service only option for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read sensors continuously or 20 seconds periodically on background you have to use [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). Workmanager is not meant to read sensors continuously or 20 seconds periodically.